# What does Ampersand do after a variable?

Tags: c++, binary, integer

```
int a = 2;
a = (a&-a);
```

So what is the purpose of '&' in this block?

The result is "2"

Comment: Possible duplicate of google.

Comment: *read*: `a = (a & (-a));`

Comment: It's the bitwise AND operator. People saying you should Google punctuation have probably never tried it, ignore them.

Comment: In C there is only one single binary operation using the ampersand.

Comment: @SteveJessop You can if you use `"` around the punctuation.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: heh, searching `C++ "&"` already brings you here. I'm surprised how good the results are, I was expecting it to be mostly irrelevant stuff that happens to have an ampersand character somewhere on the page. Obviously *I* hadn't tried it recently, it used to be pretty hopeless even with the quotes.

Comment: @MarounMaroun:  Just because you can google a question doesn't make it off-topic or inappropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: @JohnDibling Did I say so?

Comment: @MarounMaroun and you know thinking about a logical search term, something like `C++ operator` can really help narrow the field.  You don't just go up to someone and say hey do you know what the ampersand sign means?   You'd have to add context for them as well.

Comment: @MarounMaroun:  You certianly implied it with your thinly veiled "RTFM."

Comment: @JohnDibling Not exactly, people should have more sense of humor here :) BTW, you don't need to be genius to know how to search in Google, this is the minimal thing required from programmer. If he doesn't know how to, it's time to know.

Comment: Well, it does imply a lack of effort in searching which is listed as the number one sign of a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Asking a question on SO shouldn't ever be your first tactic when you don't understand a symbol in a new language... probably should consult whatever reference you are learning from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the bitwise "and" operator. It might be clearer with more space

```
a = a & -a;
```

or even

```
a = a bitand -a;
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun - ***[bitand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)*** in both C and C++.  Oh, but please don't down vote me because its a wiki link :)

Comment: I know what's bit and, I didn't know the keyword `bitand` ;)

Comment: @ryyker Don't worry, comments can't be downvoted :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is the bitwise and operator. Just take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

The combination of `a & -a` can be used to find the least significant bit that's set. Example:

```
      12 = 00001100
     -12 = 11110100
     --------------
12 & -12 = 00000100
```

Comment: Just love it when someone down votes and leaves it to the imagination of everyone why.  Is there really anything wrong with this answer?

Comment: Probably because, prior to your edit, your answer was skirting dangerously close to a link-only answer, which are discouraged.

Comment: @ryyker I think it was downvoted before the last edit. I've +1 this answer in particular for the extra information added in that edit.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` is bitwise and, but what the full statement does is filter out the first `1` in the number, e.g.

```
a    11010
~a   00101
-a   00110
a&-a 00010
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bitwise `and`,  essentially, it takes 2 variables and for each bit, it's 1 only if both numbers have a `1` at that position

so it `a` is

```
11101010
```

than `-a` is probably represented in two's compliement like

```
00010110
```

so if you and them together you get

```
11101010
00010110
---------------
00000010
```